# Is there a C++ function to calculate distance between two indexes?

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a task in codingame, called 'Lumen', that I just solved. To summarize the task: in a square array, in random indexes the letter 'C' will be placed, representing a candle. The highest luminosity 'L' (int) will be placed at the index of letter 'C' and then, the luminosity for all neighboring indexes has to be calculated, until the value of L becomes 0. So in index arr[i][j] the luminosity will be set to L, for all combinations of arr[i-1][j] will be L-1 ad so on. 
Right now, in my code, I have very lengthy 'if' based calculation, for a maximum value of L = 3 (in the task it goes lower not higher). 
Here is some example code of the calculations:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
        if (map[i][j] == 'C'){

    luminance[i][j] = L;
    if (i + 1 < N)  { luminance[i + 1][j] = L - 1; }
    if (i - 1 >=0)  { luminance[i - 1][j] = L - 1; }
    if (j + 1 < N)  { luminance[i][j + 1] = L - 1; }
    if (j - 1 >= 0) { luminance[i][j - 1] = L - 1; }
            ...
            ...
    if (i + 2 < N)  { luminance[i + 2][j] = L - 2; }
    if (i - 2 >= 0) { luminance[i - 2][j] = L - 2; } ...
```

Is there a better and less prone to bugs way to perform these calculations? I read somewhere, that essentially, this is an inverse Chebyshev distance calculation (max(|x1 -x2|,|y1-y2|).
If it is so, is there a function to calculated it in C++? I searched a little about it and found documentation for python3 and java, but not for C++.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: when you will have iterators you could use `std::distance` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: Step 1: find the position of the C, Step 2: loop over all elements E in your matrix, calculate max(L - distance(E, C), 0)

Comment: Are you intending to process every element of the array, or every element < N from the current position? Loop over those elements, and do the calculation.

Comment: Be careful about the edges of the array, or ensure your C squares are inside the array by N positions?

Comment: What if there is more than one candle?

Comment: I loop once and calculate for every neighboring cell once I find a 'C'. The loop only goes forward. I populate an array with the candle positions and the calculate on an another. That way, there can be successive candles that will not be overwritten. All I have to do is count the number of zeros left in the matrix to find the 'spots' without light.

Comment: It is easy to work with arrays, populating a std::vector<std::vector<int>> will be a bit tricky for me, since I am not very experienced. The input comes from standard input as a string, with each character separated by a space. So if str is the input, I cannot just do arr[i][j] = str[i] and get each character at an index. I plan on finding a way later on and separating the code to functions, because now everything is in main...

Comment: @Raffallo I guess `std::distance` will not work in nonlinear memory data like `std::list`

Comment: Can you use the distance formula?  Since a candle disperses its light spherically, you may want to base your loop on Polar coordinates (the distance will be the radius from the candle), then convert to rectangular to get the coordinates.  Think of this as a graphing issue on a 2d plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by finding the index of the candle, and then simply iterate over all cells:

```
int col, row;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
        if (map[i][j] == 'C') {
            col = j;
            row = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply iterate over all cells, compute the distance, and then the luminance:

```
#include <cstdlib>    // for std::abs
#include <algorithm>  // for std::max

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        int distance = std::max(std::abs(i - row), std::abs(j - col));
        luminance[i][j] = std::max(L - distance, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::abs(i - row) - std::abs(j - col);` - don't you mean to add here (in the middle)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes... Bad copy/paste... I initially used `L - std::abs(...) - std::abs(...)` directly in the call to `std::max` :) Fixed!

Comment: That is much more compact than my naive solution. I wonder why in all the advanced classes I have had, they do not go a bit deeper in the std library and algorithm creation. I am in favor of learning as you code, but it would make things more comprehensive, at least for me.

Comment: That's the right solution for a single source diminishing linearly proportionally to the maximum distance along any axis. Using manhattan-distance would be a nice variation, and generalising to any number of sources is a nice challenge.